# What is the benefit of using Animator.StringtoHash("")?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why should you use Animator.StringToHash("") while you can use animator component with strings?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Animator.StringToHash` is used for optimization purposes. Comparing two `ints` is faster than comparing two `strings`.

This is mostly used when comparing many animation state. `Animator.StringToHash` will convert the name of the animator(`string`) to an id(`int`). You can them compare animation state with integers instead of strings.

You can learn more about this [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation/animator-scripting).

Comment: Yes, My question is answered. Thanks!