# Play and wait for Animation/Animator to finish playing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my script i did that when the player is on the top of the platform move it up.
It's working fine. But now i want to make that once it got up play the clip "Down".

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;

public class DetectPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

    GameObject target;

    public void ClearLog()
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(UnityEditor.ActiveEditorTracker));
        var type = assembly.GetType("UnityEditorInternal.LogEntries");
        var method = type.GetMethod("Clear");
        method.Invoke(new object(), null);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Platform")
        {
            Debug.Log("Touching Platform");
        }

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.name == "OnTop Detector")
        {
            Debug.Log("On Top of Platform");
            GameObject findGo = GameObject.Find("ThirdPersonController");
            GameObject findGo1 = GameObject.Find("Elevator");
            findGo.transform.parent = findGo1.transform;
            target = GameObject.Find("Elevator");
            target.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Up");
        }
    }
}
```

After the line

```
target.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Up");
```

I want when it finish playing it play the down:

```
target.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Down");
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While both answers should work, another method of doing this with coroutine and the `IsPlaying` function. You use the coroutine solution if you also want to perform other task after the animation.

**For the [`Animation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.html) system**:

The old Unity animation playback system. This should **not** be used in your new Project unless you are still using old Unity version.

```
IEnumerator playAndWaitForAnim(GameObject target, string clipName)
{
    Animation anim = target.GetComponent<Animation>();
    anim.Play(clipName);

    //Wait until Animation is done Playing
    while (anim.IsPlaying(clipName))
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    //Done playing. Do something below!
    Debug.Log("Done Playing");
}
```

**For the [`Animator`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.html) system**

This is the new Unity animation playback system. This **should be used** in your new Project instead of the [`Animation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.html) API. In terms of performance, it's better to use the `Animator.StringToHash` and compare the current state by hash number instead of the [`IsName`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52376983/3785314) function which compares string since the hash is [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40190381/3785314).

Let's say that you have state names called `Jump`, `Move` and `Look`. You get their hashes as below then use the function for playing and waiting for them them below:

```
const string animBaseLayer = "Base Layer";
int jumpAnimHash = Animator.StringToHash(animBaseLayer + ".Jump");
int moveAnimHash = Animator.StringToHash(animBaseLayer + ".Move");
int lookAnimHash = Animator.StringToHash(animBaseLayer + ".Look");

public IEnumerator PlayAndWaitForAnim(Animator targetAnim, string stateName)
{
    //Get hash of animation
    int animHash = 0;
    if (stateName == "Jump")
        animHash = jumpAnimHash;
    else if (stateName == "Move")
        animHash = moveAnimHash;
    else if (stateName == "Look")
        animHash = lookAnimHash;

    //targetAnim.Play(stateName);
    targetAnim.CrossFadeInFixedTime(stateName, 0.6f);

    //Wait until we enter the current state
    while (targetAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).fullPathHash != animHash)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    float counter = 0;
    float waitTime = targetAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length;

    //Now, Wait until the current state is done playing
    while (counter < (waitTime))
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }

    //Done playing. Do something below!
    Debug.Log("Done Playing");

}
```

---

---

For a solution specifically for your particular problem with the collision callback function (`OnTriggerEnter`), there are two possible ways to do that:

**1**.Start a coroutine function to play the animation after trigger detection:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "OnTop Detector")
    {
        Debug.Log("On Top of Platform");
        GameObject findGo = GameObject.Find("ThirdPersonController");
        GameObject findGo1 = GameObject.Find("Elevator");
        findGo.transform.parent = findGo1.transform;
        target = GameObject.Find("Elevator");
        StartCoroutine(playAnim(target));
    }
}

IEnumerator playAnim(GameObject target)
{
    Animation anim = target.GetComponent<Animation>();
    anim.Play("Up");

    //Wait until Up is done Playing the play down
    while (anim.IsPlaying("Up"))
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    //Now Play Down
    anim.Play("Down");
}
```

**OR**

**2**.Make the `OnTriggerEnter` function a coroutine(IEnumerator) instead of `void` function:

```
IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "OnTop Detector")
    {
        Debug.Log("On Top of Platform");
        GameObject findGo = GameObject.Find("ThirdPersonController");
        GameObject findGo1 = GameObject.Find("Elevator");
        findGo.transform.parent = findGo1.transform;
        target = GameObject.Find("Elevator");
        Animation anim = target.GetComponent<Animation>();
        anim.Play("Up");

        //Wait until Up is done Playing the play down
        while (anim.IsPlaying("Up"))
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        //Now Play Down
        anim.Play("Down");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working. And if i want to make it will move up and down none stop ? I tried instead calling the StartCoroutine in the OnTriggerEnter to create Update function and inside the Update function i did: if (target != null)
            StartCoroutine(playAnim(target)); but this make it only move up all the time none stop and never down.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Can you explain it more?

Comment: I mean now the line StartCoroutine(playAnim(target)); make it move up and down but only once. What i want to do is that it will keep moving up down up down...none stop.

Comment: All you need is wrap the Play to down code in a `while(true)` code. Since this is not your original problem, I posted the solution  [here](http://pastebin.com/hxsXb0z2). Tell me if there is still a problem. Just like you wanted, this will Play up and Down animation forever!

Comment: Thank you, Working.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this without needing to check manually at all is to use queuing

```
target.GetComponent<Animation>().PlayQueued("Down", QueueMode.CompleteOthers);
```

This code will wait for any other animation currently playing on the object to finish before playing the queued animation.

[The Unity API page regarding this topic](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.PlayQueued.html)