# How to check if a certain animation state from an animator is running?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, animator

I created an animator called "m4a4animator". Inside it, the main function is called "idle" (nothing), and other 2 states: "shoot" (mouse0) and "reload" (R). These 2 animation states are transitioned to "idle". Now, everything is working... but the only problem I have is this: if I am in the middle of reloading and and press mouse0 (shoot), the animation running state immediately changes to shoot... but I want to block that.

Now, the question: How can I stop CERTAIN animation changes while an animation is running?

[Here is my animator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWt4A.png)

And here is my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class m4a4 : MonoBehaviour {

    public Animator m4a4animator;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.R)) {

            m4a4animator.Play("reload");

        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {

            m4a4animator.Play("shoot");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course I can.

Comment: Good question. You just had better add the picture direcly to you question, since link addresses can change.

Comment: If you are using Mecanim, then I don't think you will have to add a check for if a animation is running or not. Just tick "has exit time" on the transition of "reload --> idle". This should do the trick.

Comment: Also I would suggest you to use triggers instead of `animator.play`. These links should help:- 1)https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationParameters.html 2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N73EWquTGSY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the legacy Animation system, `Animation.IsPlaying("TheAnimatonClipName)` is used to check if the animation clip is playing.

---

For the new Mechanim Animator system, you have to check if both `anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(animLayer).IsName(stateName)` and `anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(animLayer).normalizedTime < 1.0f)` are true. If they are then animation name is currently playing.

This can be simplified like the function like the `Animation.IsPlaying` function above.

```
bool isPlaying(Animator anim, string stateName)
{
    if (anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(animLayer).IsName(stateName) &&
            anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(animLayer).normalizedTime < 1.0f)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

---

> Now, everything is working... but the only problem I have is this: if
>   I am in the middle of reloading and and press mouse0 (shoot), the
>   animation running state immediately changes to shoot... but I want to
>   block that.

When the shoot button is pressed, check if the "reload" animation is playing. If it is, don't shoot.

```
public Animator m4a4animator;
int animLayer = 0;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
    {
        m4a4animator.Play("reload");
    }

    //Make sure we're not reloading before playing "shoot" animation
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && !isPlaying(m4a4animator, "reload"))
    {
        m4a4animator.Play("shoot");
    }
}

bool isPlaying(Animator anim, string stateName)
{
    if (anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(animLayer).IsName(stateName) &&
            anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(animLayer).normalizedTime < 1.0f)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

If you need to wait for the "reload" animation to finish playing before playing the "shoot" animation then use a coroutine. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587030/play-and-wait-for-animation-animator-to-finish-playing) post described how to do so.

Answer (score 2):

There are other threads about that: https://answers.unity.com/questions/362629/how-can-i-check-if-an-animation-is-being-played-or.html

```
if (this.animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("YourAnimationName"))
{
    //your code here
}
```

this tells you if you are in a certain state.

```
Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime
```

this give you the normalized time of the animation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationState-normalizedTime.html

Try to play with those function, I hope that solve your problem