# Unity - Change character only when animation stopped

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have two objects(the same character, but, in different functions) which i want change the character when animation stop and when it runs triggered by a click. For example, I have the `Kick_Player` where there is the animation triggered by the click, and when the `Kick_Player` ends the animation, i want it automatically changes to `Player_Stopped`. The poses are different each other, 'cause this i need to do these changes.

I tried something with `this.MyAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("My_Animation")` but, i got unsuccessful tries. Is there a way to do that ?

```
public class TapController : MonoBehaviour {

    Animator Anim;

    public GameObject CharacterToController; //Kick_Player
    public GameObject CharacterToBeStopped; //Player_Stopped

     void Start(){
      Anim = CharacterToController.GetComponent<Animator>();
      CharacterToBeStopped.SetActive(false);
     }

     void Update(){
      if(input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
       if(!CharacterToController.activeSelf){
        CharacterToController.SetActive(true);
       }

       Anim.Play("Kick_Ball");


     if(!this.Anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Kick_Ball") {
        CharacterToController.SetActive(false);
        CharacterToBeStopped.SetActive(true);
      }
     }

}
```

I made this code to test, but it doesn't work

Comment: What's the value of `My_Animation`? Can you show how you're playing the animation?

Comment: you can use animation events.  https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html

Comment: What do you mean about value ? I run made a instance, after, every update trigger, It runs the animation. I will update the question with my code

Comment: You said you tried `this.MyAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("My_Animation")`? I am asking you the value of `My_Animation`. I mean the actual string you used there. It matters. I need to know what value you are comparing. Also, you should show the way you are playing or triggering(in code) the animation

Comment: @Programmer i updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `IsName` function requires that you prefix the base layer name of the animation state before the actual animation state.

The default base name is usually *"Base Layer"*

[image]

```
if(!this.Anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Base Layer.Kick_Ball")
```

Note that you have to do that outside your `if(input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){` otherwise that will never get chance to be checked.

---

I've seen reports of `IsName` not working for some people so if you do that but still have issues, consider doing it another way.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if (!CharacterToController.activeSelf)
        {
            CharacterToController.SetActive(true);
        }

        Anim.Play("Kick_Ball");

        StartCoroutine(PlayAndWaitForAnim(Anim, "Kick_Ball"));
    }
}


const string animBaseLayer = "Base Layer";
int animHash = Animator.StringToHash(animBaseLayer + ".Kick_Ball");

public IEnumerator PlayAndWaitForAnim(Animator targetAnim, string stateName)
{
    targetAnim.Play(stateName);


    //Wait until we enter the current state
    while (targetAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).fullPathHash != animHash)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    float counter = 0;
    float waitTime = targetAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length;

    //Now, Wait until the current state is done playing
    while (counter < (waitTime))
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }

    //Done playing. Do something below!
    Debug.Log("Done Playing");

    CharacterToController.SetActive(false);
    CharacterToBeStopped.SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: I'll try here and later i bring answers