# How to add random game object when my gift animation finish?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When button is pressed, random game object is selected and gift animation start, when it finish it should look like the one in image. I want my random game object to appear at ?????? when animation end. The problem is I don't know how. One more thing, how do I block button until gift animation finish, I only want 1 loot box open at a time.

[gift image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J1PP.png)

```
public class GiftValue
{
    public int GValue;
    public int GWeight;

    public GiftValue(int gvalue, int gweight)
    {
        GValue = gvalue;
        GWeight = gweight;
    }
}
public List<GiftValue> GiftwithWeight = new List<GiftValue>
{
    new GiftValue(1,        25),
    new GiftValue(2,        25),
    new GiftValue(3,        25),
    new GiftValue(4,        20),
    new GiftValue(5,        5),
};

private readonly List<int> _GiftList = new List<int>();
public Animator OpenGiftAnimation;
public Text txtSellGiftAmount;
private int GiftAmount=10; 

private void Start()
{
    foreach (GiftValue kvp in GiftwithWeight)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < kvp.GWeight; i++)
        {
            _GiftList.Add(kvp.GValue);
        }
    }

}
public int GetRandomNumber()
{
    // get a random inxed from 0 to 99
    int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, _GiftList.Count);
    // get the according value

    return _GiftList[randomIndex];

}
public void OpenGiftBtn()
{
    if(GiftAmount>0)
    {

        OpenGiftAnimation.Play("OpenAnimation", -1, 0f);
        int itemGiftNumber = GetRandomNumber();
        int itemGiftIndex = GiftwithWeight.FindIndex(w => w.GValue == itemGiftNumber);
        GiftAmount--;
        txtSellGiftAmount.text = GiftAmount.ToString();
        Debug.Log($"The odds for this were {GiftwithWeight[itemGiftIndex].GWeight / 100f:P} !");


    }

}
```

Comment: The underlaying main question -> [Play and wait for Animation/Animator to finish playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587030/play-and-wait-for-animation-animator-to-finish-playing) | Then for adding object to the scene -> [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) or I would actually rather already have one in the Giftbox prefab and only change it's sprite/properties accordingly. Then you could simply animate its position within the animation itself

Comment: You could add an animation event at the end of the animation and that could call a routine to generate the object

Comment: @derHugo sorry, for late reply, It work using your first link. But I don't understand the next one. Do you mean I add it in Giftbox prefab and show it using animation event like BugFinder said?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Invoke method. Let's say that your whole animation takes 5 seconds, so make a method called "AfterAnimation":

```
Invoke("AfterAnimation",5.0f);

public void AfterAnimation()
 {
// after animation code goes here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for working with animator and random items - it's just spawn your object at start of animation and show it only when it wants.
For example you can use next flow in animator (also, you can show/hide "Claim"/etc. buttons while changing states of animator):

[image]