# Play in sequence of 4 game objects - animators (Not single animator with multiple states) in a queue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I'm new to unity. I have 4 GameObjects say Red, Green, Blue, Yellow - with index mapped 0, 1, 2 and 3 respectively. Also, I kept index sequence in the list `List<int> systemTrack`.
Now, I'm calling the sequence of `animator` with respect to list `{ 0, 1, 2, 3 }` (this can be random 0-3).

I can perform one animator loop at a given time.

```
 void Start() {
    animator.Play("blue_animation", 0, 0);
 }
```

**How can I call in sequence based on list ? Perhaps `Update()` is right place to call.**

So far I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40587340/3632832) - But it has single Animator object with multiple state called in sequence which is not my case.
Few others discussions also available for `Animation` component Not for the `new Animator` component.

Comment: please use the correct tags ... [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now ... your code is clearly `c#`

Answer (score 0):

In your current class you could use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) like

```
List<AnimatorQueueController> animatorQueues;

private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(RunAllControllersSequencial());
}

IEnumerator RunAllControllersSequencial()
{
    foreach (var queue in animatorQueues)
    {
        // This runs the routine and waits until it finishes
        yield return queue.RunAnimationQueueAndWait();
    }
}
```

Now the only thing to do is define/implement how each if these controllers "knows", that its own animation queue has finished.

There are probably many possible ways to go. Straight away: None of them will be beautiful ;) Since the `Animator` uses a lot of `string` based stuff you always will end up either having to make sure all animation/trigger names are written correctly, or you will have to reference the animationClip and either hope the state is called the same or you have to expensively find the states via the according clip, you'd have to know how much time to wait for the queue to finish, etc.

This said, also this solution won't be perfect but in my opinion for your setup it would be the most convenient ;)

You could e.g. use an [Animation Event](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html) and do something like

```
public class AnimationQueueController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Animator _animator;
    // Here set the first state name for each instance via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private string firstStateName = "first_state";

    private void Awake ()
    {
        if(!_animator) _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Simply have another routine you can yield so it is executed and at the same time waits until it is done
    public IEnumerator RunAnimationQueueAndWaitUntilEnd()
    {
        hasReachedEnd = false;
        _animator.Play(firstStateName, 0 ,0);

        yield return new WaitUntil(() => hasReachedEnd);
    }

    // This is the method you will invoke via the Animation Event
    // See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html
    public void AnimationEnd()
    {
        hasReachedEnd = true;
    }
}
```

This at least reduces your implementation overhead to

- make sure you fire the Animation Event at the end of the last state
- make sure you provide the name of the first state in the `AnimatorQueueController`
- in your original script instead of `Animator` references rather store the `AnimatorQueueController` in your list