# Play animation 5 times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to play my animator's animation 5 times. That is after every animation that ends, it has to replay it for another time.  How do I do this?

```
public Animator anim;

void Start ()
       {
             StartCoroutine(PlayAnimInterval(5));
       }

      private IEnumerator PlayAnimInterval(int n)
      {
          while (n > 0)
          {
              anim.Play("wave", -1, 0F);
              --n;
              //yield return new WaitForSeconds(anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length); //Returns 1 which is wrong
          }
      }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Play and wait for Animation/Animator to finish playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587030/play-and-wait-for-animation-animator-to-finish-playing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `for` loop in `IEnumerator` to solve the problem. Also make sure you enter the layer number correctly. Here the wave state is repeated 5 times in layer zero.

```cs
private IEnumerator PlayAnimInterval(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        anim.Play("wave", 0, 1);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length);
    }
}
```

---

### How to detect Animator Layer?

The animator layer is an array. By adding each layer in the layers section, its index is also added. You can find its code below.

[image]

---

### Repeat State Info with Behaviour

In this method you can solve the problem of repetition in any state. Just create a behavior like the one below and just add the number of repetitions.  This method also works independently of the layer.

[image]

[image]

```cs
public class Repeat : StateMachineBehaviour
{
    public int repeatTime;
    public override void OnStateExit(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        if (repeatTime <= 0) return;
        
        repeatTime--;
        animator.Play(stateInfo.fullPathHash);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but ```anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length``` returns 1 for me. Why?

Comment: @Vika If the layer is not selected correctly, it will always be 1. The initial layer is zero.

Comment: The layer for me is "Base Layer" which should always be 0 right? So why is it causing problem and displaying as 1 for length?

Comment: @Vika If you run into a problem the first way, the problem may be from another part, but I added another method to the answer that is much better than IEnumerator. You can repeat any other behavior you want.